# using simpleopenni with kinect for windows sdk 1.6 - unable to get data

Tags: windows, kinect, processing, simple-openni

I am trying to use the simpleopenni library to access data from my Kinect in Processing. 
However, when I try to access my Kinect using the library, I get errors like "Can't open the depthMap, maybe the camera is not connected!".

I have followed all installation instructions, and have verified that openNI2 64-bit is functional by successfully running and interacting with the NI Viewer included with the install.

I have verified that NITE2 64 bit is functional by successfully running and interacting with the simple user tracker included with the install.

I have the official MS Kinect for Windows SDK 1.6 installed on my system, and I understand that v2 of open ni and simpleopenni are able to work with the official SDK instead of libfreenect.

I'm not sure how to debug further from here...any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you point to where you read that OpenNI can use the Kinect for Windows SDK libraries, instead of libfreenect?  I've not read this before, and not sure it is the case.

Comment: Sure, right in the release notes for OpenNI2:

http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-release-notes/#.UWODXeejNBk

Check the last item in the changelog.

Comment: Wow, there it is!  I'm off to check it all out, I hadn't known about this previously.